# Bounds on sums and integrals

Tags: integration, summation

Consider a function $f(x)$, where $0<f(x)
~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then it seems fairly intuitive (at least for finite $n$) that

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)\right)^2\ge\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)^2,$$

because in the LHS we get cross terms that do not appear in the RHS.

However, this intuition does not carry across to the integral case: in particular, I can find an example function such that

$$\left(\int_0^1\mathrm{d}xf(x)\right)^2<\int_0^1\mathrm{d}xf(x)^2$$

($f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$).

I'm used to sums and integrals behaving 'pretty much' the same way, as one is a limit of the other, so what is going on here?  Why do the similar constructions give different results?

(PS I'm a physicist not a mathematician, go easy on me!)

Comment: You're looking at Schwarz' Inequality, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchwarzsInequality.html

Comment: @Gerry I certainly see that the integral inequality above satisfies Schwarz's Inequality, thanks for pointing to that.  I don't entirely understand why the sum version doesn't: is it because I'm missing a factor of $n$ to account for the 'width' of the sums?

Comment: Yes. The discrete version would be $$\left(\sum_1^nf(i)\right)^2\le n\sum_1^n(f(i))^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral inequality is not really a generalization of the sum inequality. You can think of this in terms of Riemann sums, where $\Delta$ is the spacing of the rectangles:

$$\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right)^2 \approx \left(\sum_i f(i)\Delta\right)^2 \qquad \text{but} \qquad \int_0^1 f^2(x) dx \approx \sum_i f^2(i)\Delta$$
As you can see, the $\Delta$ is not squared in the right Riemann sum, so we cannot really compare the first and second inequality directly.

Comment: The claim for sums explicitly stated $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'll edit the answer. ;)